# Charles doesn't show form "Connection from"

Tags: charles-proxy

[image]

After i'm set in wifi proxy-http correct server and port, that window still doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my **mac-mini**!
I'm connected to router in two ways:
**1. through ethernet
2. through wifi ( was turned off! )**

So, disable ethernet, and enable wifi. And in charles -> settings -> local ip you will see, that your ip address has been changed!

Maybe this question / answer will help somebody!